# Output every x iterations in a for-loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

So I have this code:

```
for (int i=1000; i<2016; i++ )
{
    cout << "The year is " <<  i << endl;
}
```

But let's say I don't want this code to print all of the years, but just a select few, let's say it's the years 500, 1000, 1500 and 2000.

I tried to add this to the code:

```
for (int i=1000; i<2016; i++ )

          if ( i == 500 , i == 1000 , i == 1500 , i == 2000){
    cout << "The year is " <<  i << endl;
}
```

but that didn't work.

How would I make the code write only the years I picked?

p.s. The interval is random and not every 500.

Comment: Take a look at some C++ tutorials.  Focus on conditional logic operators.

Comment: I think you're missing some basic programming knowledge based on this question..

Comment: @NightShadeQueen: Probably c++.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted so much?  Very valid and useful question.

Answer (score 8):

If you want something to happen every 100 iterations, use the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator `%`:

```
 for (int i=500; i<20000; i++) {
   if (i % 100 == 0) cout << i << endl;
```

Your code is incorrect, because you are wrongly using (without wanting it) the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), so your test is equivalent to `if (i==2000)`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing `||`(OR) between every if-condition. It would be something like

```
if ( i == 500 || i == 1000 || i == 1500 || i == 2000)
```

Comment: Yes, that worked) can you pls explaine why what i wrote didn't work?

Comment: Because you are using (wrongly) the comma operator, as I mentionned in my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you know the years in advance:

```
const auto Years[] = {500, 742, 1000, 1234, 2000, 2015};

for (auto year : Years)
   std::cout << "The year is " << year << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much of a C++ programmer, but it seems like the most straightforward way to perform your task is:

```
for (int i = 500; i < 2016; i += 500) {
    cout << "The year is " << i << endl;
}
```

Comment: And what if the years are random?

Comment: That wasn't the question, but if they're random then there are a couple choices. My preferred answer would be to create an array of the random years then look through the array - something other than iterating 20,000 times and doing a set of compares each time to find the answer.

    years_to_print = [300, 734, 888]; // or generate based on a rule

Then loop through the elements of the vector/array.

Comment: If you provide the specific problem I can provide a better answer.